# Thymeleaf - Populate ang get language property values

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

**Circumstances**

I'm using Spring Boot with Thymeleaf for populating my HTML template files and get back the result as a String. For that I used `SpringTemplateEngine`.

The code looks like this

```
    Context context = new Context();
    context.setVariables(myProperties);
    return templateEngine.process(htmlTemplateName, context);
```

**The problem**
I want to achieve something similar, but with language.property files

I have two language property files: language.properties and language_en.properties which looks like this

`my.value = This a string containing a dummy name = {name}`

**What I want to achieve?**

1. I want to use thymeleaf to reach the correct language property file
2. Populate the `{name}` variable with a defined variable. The templating should be based on variable name like in HTMLs eg: hashmap: <"name", "FooName">
3. Get back the populated text as String. I don't have HTML file, I just want to use the templating mechanism of the thymeleaf.

**Question**

Is it possible and how can I do that?
What is the right formatting in language.properties if it's possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can!

You need to configure a `MessageSource` bean with the correct basename to your message files in your resource directory, like:
`spring.messages.basename=path/to/language`, assuming your properties files are located at `path/to/language(_en).properties`
Given this bean, wherever you need a translated string, you inject an instance of `MessageSource` and use that to get your translated string for a given message `key`:

```
public class I18NHelper {

    private final MessageSource messageSource;

    public I18NHelper(final MessageSource messageSource) {
        this.messageSource = messageSource;
    }
    
    public String translate(String key, String name) {
        return messageSource.getMessage(key, new Object[] {name}, Locale.ENGLISH);
    }
}
```

Edit: Fixed the class to inject and the call to getMessage.
Also, there multiple ways to get the Locale of the current Session or the System. I used the English locale as an example. Adjust to your needs.

Comment: The messages.getMessage is not a valid function if the Messages are from `org.thymeleaf.expression.Messages`

Comment: You are correct, I fixed the code, please check my edit. The class to inject should be MessageSource, not Messages.